# Roblox script erroring

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out what's the problem. Any help?

```
local petModule = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("PetModule"))

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player) end
    
    if player.leaderstats.Cash.Value >= 500 then
        
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 500
        
        local pet = petModule.chooseRandomPet()
        
        print(pet.Name.." selected")
    end
end)
```

Comment: there are no syntax errors in your code, which means that the problem involves some element of the Roblox frameworkd. Could you be a little more specific please and tell us which error is presented, and in which line the error occurs

Comment: The error says this, Workspace.Model.Sign.ClickDetector.Script:5: Expected ')' (to close '(' at line 3), got 'if'

Comment: try to remove the `end` near `function(player)`, you are already closing the function at the final `end` in the code, if you close right next to function, it will cause an error

Comment: Okay I tried it but it did another error,  ClickDetector is not a valid member of ClickDetector.

Comment: TuoWorld, these error messages that you've posted here in the comments should go in your question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intead of:

```lua
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
```

try:

```lua
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
```

to solve your `ClickDetector` problem